# Calculating Skew Symmetric Matrix determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices, skew-symmetric-matrices

I've been solving matrix related questions and I'm confused for this one:

> If A is a 5 * 5 matrix, where A^t= - A (A transpose equal to negative A) then what is the determinant for
> A?  There are 4 options:
>  a) 1
>  b) -1
>  c) 2
>  d) 0

I thought it was zero (d) since it's an odd sized matrix but book says
it's 2, how so?

Comment: You are right. Time to buy a better book perhaps.

Comment: Ah, printing mistakes.. I was losing my mind over this problem. Thanks for the reply